# How to use Variable in a prompt?

Tags: octave

I want to take input some integer value and prompt the user to answer the same number of question.

I have used `G(kk) = input(["Enter %c Permanant Load", ii])`; but getting some error

error shows "implicit conversion from numeric to char"

```
%% For creating load combinations  

ii = input("Number of Permanant Loads");  
jj = input("Number of Variable Loads");  

for kk = 1:ii  
  G(kk) = input(["Enter %c Permanant Load", ii]);  
endfor  

G  

Enter 1 Permanant Load  

Enter 2 Permenant Load
```

Comment: 'Some error' is quite vague, please [edit] the question to contain that error message, they are usually quite descriptive

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly convert your numeric value (ii) to a String before you can insert it into a string.

This could be done using the [mat2str](https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.1/Converting-Numerical-Data-to-Strings.html) function.

The following should work correctly:

```matlab
G(kk) = input(["Enter " mat2str(ii) " Permanant Load"]);
```

Note:
Although I suspect what you really may want is:

```matlab
G(kk) = input(["Enter " mat2str(kk) " Permanant Load"]);
```